# Protractor: Syntax to select elements based on html attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, automated-tests

I want to select this element:

```
 <span class="required" ng-class="{'disabled': saveInProgress}" 
 input-control="{okCallback:setFieldValue, params:['firstName'], 
 title:'First Name', value: person.firstName, 
 validate:{length:100},empty:false}">
     <span hs-placeholder="Type First Name" class="ng-binding"></span>
 </span>
```

And this one too:

```
 <span class="required" ng-class="{'disabled': saveInProgress}" 
  input-control="{okCallback:setFieldValue, params:['lastName'], 
  title:'Last Name', value: person.lastName, validate:{length:100}}">
      <span hs-placeholder="Type Last Name" class="ng-binding">
      </span>
 </span>
```

I tried to do so using

```
 var input = element(by.css('span.required span.ng-binding'));  
 browser.actions().mouseMove(input).click().perform();
```

But it kept on calling the first name element only. Any ideas? please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
element.all(by.css('span.required span.ng-binding')).get(0) //to access 1st element
element.all(by.css('span.required span.ng-binding')).get(1) //to access 2nd element
```

because in dom there are two elements available for the selector

```
by.css('span.required span.ng-binding')
```

if you use

```
 element(by.css('span.required span.ng-binding'))
```

then protractor by default will take the first displayed element.

Hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)